# adding a foreign key failed on phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've being trying this all night and still can't get it done, here is what the auto generated query:

```
ALTER TABLE  `avatar` ADD FOREIGN KEY (  `characterID` ) REFERENCES `201701_481_g02`.`character_table` (

`characterID`
) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT ;
```

the error message:

## 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`201701_481_g02`.`#sql-6595d_522e8`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-6595d_522e8_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`characterID`) REFERENCES `character_table` (`characterID`))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation for this behavior is rows in the `avatar` table that have a value for `characterID` that doesn't appear in `character_table`.

We can use a query with an anti-join pattern to identify those values. e.g.

```
  SELECT a.characterID
    FROM `avatar` a
    LEFT
    JOIN `201701_481_g02`.`character_table` c
      ON c.characterID = a.characterID
   WHERE c.characterID IS NULL
```

With those values identified, we can either create rows in the referenced table with appropriate values in the `characterID` column. Or we can either remove or modify the rows in `avatar`.

---

I think different error raised when there's not an index with the referenced column(s) as the leading columns.  And if the datatypes of the two columns don't match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

For Error code 1452 according to Mysql documentation,

> Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child table.
>
> It will reject any INSERT or UPDATE operation that attempts to create a foreign key value in a child table if there is no a matching candidate key value in the parent table.

So, in your case the foreign key *characterID* on child table(*avatar*) has no matching candidate key value in the parent table(*character_table*)